# Difference between using "expose" in dockerfile and docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am wondering what is the difference between using `EXPOSE` in a Dockerfile and in a Docker-Compose file?

What if it is declared in one file and not the other? Or what if it is declared in both but with different port numbers?

Answer (score 12):

EXPOSE in `Dockerfile` is a just a metadata information. Which tells docker when someone uses `docker run -P` which ports need to be Exposed.

Using them in compose or docker run is a dynamic way of specifying these ports. So an image like `nginx` or `apache` which is always supposed to run on port 80 inside the container will use `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile itself.

While an image which has dynamic port which may be controlled using an environment variable will then use expose in `docker run` or `compose file`

```
docker run -e UI_PORT=5556 --expose 5556 -P ....
```

Comment: thanks. I am relatively new to Docker and i struggle a bit to understand how to interpreter your answers. What happen if ports are exposed differently in the 2 files and i build and start from docker-compose?

Comment: That means both ports are exposed

Comment: Is specifying both redundant? Or is it enough for an image to have a `EXPOSE` comand on the Dockerfile so that other services declared in the same docker-compose.yml file can directly find it?